# How would I say: "If VALUE decreases:"?

Tags: python

I want to write an `if` statement that basically says: if VALUE decreases: do something.

Is this the way to go about this? Or should I try to make a list that updates itself with the values and then compare it afterwards?

Comment: so do u wanna compare two values?

Comment: `if new_value < old_value:`

Comment: You don't need a list, just two variables: The old value and the current value.  Then compare those.

Answer (score 2):

A value in itself is not increasing or decreasing, it's a number (a scalar). You need to define "decreasing" in different terms. Over time? Then since last time something happened, or over the last two weeks? From then, you can think of your code iteratively and infer what "decreasing" means. For example, you can store a value as "previous_value" and compare it to the current value, then perform an action based on the outcome.

```
previous_item = 9999999999999 # this value depends on what you are dealing with

for item in my_list:
    if item < previous_item:
        print("smallest so far:", item)
```

If instead your program works in an infinite loop (for example, some sensor-fetching function in a microcontroller):

```
class Sensor:
    def __init__(self, initial_value=0):
        self.value = initial_value


def fetch_value():
    # hit an API, read a microcontroller input…
    return ...


def on_update(state, new_value):
    if new_value < state.value:
        print("New value is smaller")

    state.value = new_value


def main():
    state = Sensor()

    while True:
        sleep(1)
        new_value = fetch_value()
        on_update(state, new_value)
```

Comment: Right! That totally makes sense. But say that I have a number that gets updated every second or so (not in a list), is there a way for me to compare this number to what it was 1 second ago? Or do I need to make a list? Thanks for your input.

Comment: Yes, the list was just an example to show a program in an iterative fashion (iteration means to keep doing the same thing over and over again). If you split your code in a way that makes sense, you may have a function named `on_update`, which is called every second and serves, evidently, to update the stored value. In this function, you can compare the new value to the previous value and perform the relevant action.